# PHP HTML output

Tags: php, html

What is the correct way to output html inside a switch structure?

I've tried both below, none work:

```
<?php
switch($x){

case "a":
$var = <<< EOM;
...the html...
EOM;
break;

case "b":
...some code...
break;

}
?>
```

OR
<?php
switch($x){

```
case "a":
?>
...the html...
<?php
break;

case "b":
...some code...
break;

}
?>
```

More info:

```
switch ($_REQUEST['act']){

    case 'editdiretorio':
    
    $sql="select * from diretorio where did=$_GET[edit]";
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
    
    ?>
    <h1>Cadastro de Serviço</h1>
    <form id="fdiretorio" method="post" action="diretorioconfirm.php">
    <?php if($edit){echo "<input name='act' type='hidden' value='update'>";?>
           Nome completo de quem preenche o questionário:<br />
      <input type="text" name="dnome" class="form-default" style="width:200px;" value="<?php echo "$row[dnome]";?>"/>
      <br />
```

... more 400 lines of code ...

```
<?php
break;

case "b":
... other code ...
```

Comment: what do you mean by "don't work"? By the looks of it the second example should work. The first one should also work, you'r just not echoing the HTML ...
I think you'll have to give us more information ...

Comment: Ok there was an sintax error. I'm truly sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correct way.  Outputting HTML within a switch is the same as outputting it anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

There's no correct way perse, both should work.

In your first example you need to make sure there is no space between <<< and EOM and no semicolon afterwards.

Example:

```
$myvar = <<<END
<div>My html here</div>
END;
echo $myvar;
```

another option would be to use:

```
echo "<div>My html here</div>";
```

Comment: I would definitely vote for the first option. It tends to be a lot less messy when outputting a lot of HTML. Of course, if you are going to be working with large amounts of HTML, a template engine like Smarty makes things a LOT cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The second example should work, except you said `<php` instead of `<?php`

Comment: Yup, and the first one doesn't generate an output... it's just storing the value in a database

Comment: Also, in the second case, he forgot <?php as well